# Proper handling of user input

Tags: asp.net, user-input, html-encode

So I'm setting up my form validation, inputs, error messages etc... and then realized a lot of the info that I'm collecting will need to be output again at some point.

So I wrapped my inputs in:

```
Server.HtmlEncode(txtbox.text);
```

What else should I be doing to ensure that i avoid XSS types of attacks?  Should I be be doing something when I write the data to the page as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a security point of view, our Web forms are naked and 100% vulnerable. We need to look at all the ways data is passed to them and test as appropriate:

```
* Form Fields
* URL Query Strings
* Cookies
* Database
* ViewState
```

MSDN Design Guidelines for Secure Web Applications:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302420.aspx

Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx

The Code Analysis Tool (CAT.NET):
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0178e2ef-9da8-445e-9348-c93f24cc9f9d&displaylang=en

ASP.NET Data Input Validation:
http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/11/01/ASPNET-Data-Input-Validation.aspx:

EDIT:
Coming soon, the new Web Protection Library CTP:
http://blogs.msdn.com/securitytools/archive/2009/10/17/web-protection-library-ctp-release-coming-soon.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998274.aspx specific for .NET 1.0/2.0 XSS

Comment: Here is a good cheat sheet
http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Also read Jeff's posts here
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/safe-html-and-xss/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to HtmlEncode when you output data to the page, not when you collect it. From [Stack Overflow podcast #58](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/podcast-58/):

> Don’t HTML encode data that’s stored in your database! Take the [good advice of Damien Guard](http://damieng.com/blog/2007/12/18/5-signs-your-aspnet-application-may-be-vulnerable-to-html-injection) and Joel Spolsky! You can choose to store both representations, but don’t store just the HTML; go with the raw data at the highest level of precision.

**Links**

- [5 signs your ASP.NET application may be vulnerable to HTML injection](http://damieng.com/blog/2007/12/18/5-signs-your-aspnet-application-may-be-vulnerable-to-html-injection)
- [How To: Prevent Cross-Site Scripting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998274.aspx) - specific for .NET 1.0/2.0
- [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Cheat Sheet](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html)
- [Safe HTML and XSS](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/safe-html-and-xss/)